# How to programmatically see whats is inside a zip in android (without unzip)

Tags: java, android, unzip, zip

I'm making an app for android and a need to check if the user's zip file entry is in the right format before unzip it, to avoid waste of time unziping. Could anyone help me?

PS.: I just need to know the name of the files inside the zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipFile.html): it uses random access to jump between file positions in the zip archive:

```
try (ZipFile file = new ZipFile("file.zip")) {
    final Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = file.entries();
    while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        final ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
        System.out.println(entry.getName());
    }
}
```